# Windows Phone, sqlite and relationships

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to have relations in sqlite on Windows Phone?
Right now I have 2 data models, `Artist` and `Album` which should have a many-to-many relationship.

Normally I would do something like

```
public class Artist
{
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}


public class Album
{
    public List<Artist> Artists{ get; set; }
}
```

but that doesn't work on Windows Phone.

So my question is:

- Are relationships possible in sqlite and WP?
- Is there an ORM for me to use, or do I need to retrieve and populate every entity by hand?

Comment: I haven't used it in a while so I'm just going to comment and not answer, but I had success in the past with [Vici Coolstorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home).

Comment: @MichaelItzoe Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it does not support Windows Phone 8.1, only 8.0. Currently I lack the time to learn how to retarget the nuget package to 8.1.